# Given a 200x200 RGB PNG file , extract the 2 least significant bits of each pixel data to create a new 200x200 image saved to disk

Tags: java, opencv, steganography

Here is the code, I am getting black image.

```
package example;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class imageCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        File f = null;
        try {
            f = new File("E:\\unnamed.png");
            img = ImageIO.read(f);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {
                int p = img.getRGB(j, i);
                int k = p << -2 >>> -2; 
                img.setRGB(j, i, k);                    
            }
        }           
        try {
            f = new File("E:\\Output.png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }    
}
```

png

Comment: Please Provide the full java code for the above question !!

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: i haven't tried because it was an interview question and i skipped it. I coudn't understand it. Can anyone provide the java code for this problem

Comment: As an aside, normally, for interviews, you have to agree not to publish the questions or code. How do you think a potential employer will regard you if they notice this question?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts We could consider this as a chance to tell the potential employer to get his class naming, variable scoping and exception handling right. Beyond that, I'm torn: That's one of the cases where it's hard to be "welcoming", and I wonder where the upvote comes from, but the topic is interesting enough that I'd give it a try...

Comment: Since it's tagged OpenCV, I'd say: 1) `imread` the image 2) `bitwise_and` with a mask full of 3s, 3) `imwrite` the result.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the 2 bits? Construct the new image from them? If it was only one bit it would be easy to write black or white, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here...

Comment: can someone convert this to python